# Prove that$(1-\omega+\omega^2)(1-\omega^2+\omega^4)(1-\omega^4+\omega^8)…$ to 2n factors$=2^{2n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, roots, products

Prove that $(1-\omega+\omega^2)(1-\omega^2+\omega^4)(1-\omega^4+\omega^8)…$ to 2n factors$=2^{2n}$ where $\omega$ is the cube root of unity

**My attempt:**

$(1+\omega^n+\omega^{2n})=0$
$\Rightarrow (1-\omega^n+\omega^{2n})=-2\omega^n$
$\Rightarrow \prod_{n=1 \to 2n}(-2\omega^n) =2^{2n}\omega^{1+2+3…2n}$
$\Rightarrow \prod_{n=1 \to 2n}(-2\omega^n) =2^{2n}\omega^{n(2n+1)}$

If $n$ is $3k$ type: $2^{2n}\omega^{n(2n+1)}=2^{2n}\omega^{3m}=2^{2n}$

If $n$ is $3k+1$ type: $2^{2n}\omega^{n(2n+1)}=2^{2n}\omega^{3m}=2^{2n}$

If $n$ is $3k+2$ type: $2^{2n}\omega^{n(2n+1)}=2^{2n}\omega^{(3k+2)(6k+5)} =2^{2n}\omega^{(3m+1)}=2^{2n}\omega^{3m}\omega=2^{2n}\omega$

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: It is not clear at all what is the general term in your product. Who said $1+ω^n+ω^{2n}=0$? Is that so for $n=3$? But wait, we don't have the term with $n=3$. What terms do we have, then?

Comment: @Ivan Neretin I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that $\omega$ is the cube root of unity. I'm just too used to using $\omega$ exclusively for cube roots of unity

Comment: @WW1 I'm sorry I forgot to mention $\omega$ is the cube root of unity I have edited the question now though

Comment: @IvanNeretin I see my mistake now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** Evaluate first few factors and see.
$$
1st : (1-\omega+\omega^2)=-2\omega \\
2nd : (1-\omega^2+\omega^4)=-2\omega^2 \\
1st \times 2nd = \ldots \\
3rd : (1-\omega^4+\omega^8)=-2\omega \\
4th : (1-\omega^8+\omega^{16})= \ldots
$$

Can you complete?

Comment: I think this is a much better solution than the other one here, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Since $$a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2),$$ we obtain: $$\prod_{k=1}^{2n}(1-w^{2^{k-1}}+w^{2^{k}})=\prod_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{\left(1+w^{3\cdot2^{k-1}}\right)}{1+w^{2^{k-1}}}=\frac{2^{2n}}{((1+w)(1+w^2))^n}=2^{2n}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\omega$ is the third root of unity, and also since $2^{2n}-1\equiv 0 \mod{3}$

$$
\begin{align}
1+\omega^{2^{i}}+\omega^{2^{i+1}}&=0\\
\\
1-\omega^{2^{i}}-\omega^{2^{i+1}}&=2\omega^{2^{i}}\\
\\
\prod_{i=0}^{2n-1}{\left(1-\omega^{2^{i}}+\omega^{2^{i+1}}\right)}&=\prod_{i=0}^{2n-1}{\left(2\omega^{2^{i}}\right)}\\
&=2^{2n}\omega^{2^{2n}-1}\\
&=2^{2n}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer is essentially the same as Michael Rozenberg's, but I couldn't help posting my answer here anyways (although the calculation is the same, my approach to this was different).

Each term is a 3-term geometric progression, and the common ratio is $-\omega^{2^{k-1}}$. The product is now $$\prod^{2n}_{k=1} \frac{(-\omega^{2^{k-1}})^3 - 1}{-\omega^{2^{k-1}}-1}$$

Using the fact that $\omega^3 = 1$, this reduces to $$\prod^{2n}_{k=1} \frac{2}{\omega^{2^{k-1}}+1}$$

As $k$ varies from $0,1,2,3,4,5,6....2n$ it can be observed that every consecutive pair of $\omega^{2^{k-1}}$ reduces to $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ by using $\omega^3 = 1$.

This gives us $n$ identical pairs of a fraction $\frac{1}{\omega+1}\cdot\frac{1}{\omega^2+1} = 1$. Product of all these fractions is $1$, which leaves the original product as $2^{2n}$.